# Java 11: Compiler does not recognize annotation processors specified in module-info.java

Tags: javac, java-11, annotation-processing

I have a Maven project called Annot which contains an annotation "MyAnnot" and a processor for it and another plain Java project called UseAnnot that contains MyAnnot(a class called User.java is annotated with it. 
When I specified that UseAnnot used the "com.home.Proc" processor in the Annot module using the META-INF.services directory, everything worked fine, but now that I am using java 11 and have put "uses javax.annotation.processing.Processor" and "provides Processor with com.home.Proc" in their respective module-info files, the compiler does not recognize the annotation processor.

I have tried the following commands in Windows cmd:

```
    javac -cp .;%USERPROFILE%\IdeaProjects\Annot\target\Annot-1.0- 
    SNAPSHOT.jar com\learn\User.java

    javac --module-path 
    %USERPROFILE%\IdeaProjects\Annot\target\Annot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
    com\learn\User.java
```

This is the Annot module-info file:

```
    import javax.annotation.processing.Processor;

    module Annot {
        requires java.compiler;
        exports com.home;
        provides Processor with com.home.Proc;
    }
```

This is the UseAnnot module-info file:

```
    module UseAnnot {
        requires java.compiler;
        requires Annot;
        uses javax.annotation.processing.Processor;
    }
```

UseAnnot\src\com\learn\User.java looks like this:

```
    package com.learn;

    import com.home.MyAnnot;

    @MyAnnot
    public class User {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            System.out.println("User main method");
        }
    }
```

I expected a HelloWorld.txt file to be generated and a message from Messager telling me that the annotation processor had been reached, like it had with the META-INF directory, but with the first command (with -cp) I got no output and with the second, I got the following:

```
    com\learn\User.java:3: error: package com.home is not visible
    import com.home.MyAnnot;
      ^
      (package com.home is declared in module Annot, which is not in                         
    the module graph)
    1 error
```

I have managed to compile it with IntelliJ when I check the "Obtain processors from classpath" option in Settings>Build, Execution, and Deployment>Compiler>Annotation Processors. I have also explicitly stated the processor in command prompt before and it worked then. However, javac won't work. Is that the only way to do it, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If the annotation processor is compiled as a module then I assume it should be deployed on the "processor module path", (java --processor-module-path).

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But do I have to give the processor module path separately?